# random number generator in php

Tags: php

i wrote a php script to generate random values between 1 and 99999999999999999999 (that's 20 9's).

The script is like this:

```
$maxq=20;
for($i=1;$i<=$maxq;$i++) {
    $min=pow(10,$i);
    $max=(pow(10,$i)*10)-1;
    echo $min."<br>";
    echo $max."<br>";
    echo mt_rand($min,$max)."<br>----<br>";
}
```

but after 10 digit, php generates scientific notations like **1.0E+19** and the random numbers generated are a mess.

I guess think is because of my hardware imitations (OS: Win XP 32 bit).

What can i do to over come this? any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could generate *n* random digits and concatenate them into one large string.

```
function randomDigits($numDigits) {
    if ($numDigits <= 0) {
        return '';
    }

    return mt_rand(0, 9) . randomDigits($numDigits - 1);
}

// Or an iterative approach
function randomDigitsLame($numDigits) {
    $digits = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numDigits; ++$i) {
        $digits .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }

    return $digits;
}

$maxq = 20;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxq; $i++) {
    echo $i . "<br>\n";
    echo randomDigits($i) . "<br>\n----<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: exactly what i was writing now :)
Thanks for your script strager

Comment: Why do you call the iterative approach lame? Surely in this situation it is better than your recursive solution, as you don't have to push and pop variables on a stack, and you aren't needlessly making your stack 20 deep (which could cause a StackOverflow).

Comment: @bramp, Pssh.  It's lame.  Get over it.  =]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [BC Math Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) to overcome the limit. Or if you aren't going to be doing calculations with your random number, you can create a random 20 digit string. Something like:

```
$num = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
   $num .= mt_rand(0, 9);
echo $num;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In windows platform it can be use getrandmax()  ,it gives only 32768.
2. so you need  range larger than 32768.
3. specifying min and max
4. It will allow you to create a range larger than 32768
5. so it will consider using mt_rand() instead of getrandmax()

For Example,

```
<?php
echo rand() . "\n";
echo rand() . "\n";

echo rand(5, 15);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I build upon "bramp" response. I wanted 25 lines, of 25 randomly generated digits:

```
<?php
  $num = '';
  while($i < 25)
  {
    for ($n = 0; $n < 25; $n++)
      $num .= mt_rand(0, 9);
      echo $num . "</br>";
  $num = '';
  $i++;
  }
?>
```