# PHP: (not so) random variable

Tags: php, random

I want to make a small script what generates the barcode is the barcode field is empty.
I want the barcode to be = 21xxxxxxxx and the x-es are random int numbers (min 0 max 9)

So far my code is:

```
if ($barcode = NULL) {
    Array($a);
    for ($i=3;$i<10;$i++){ 
        $a = rand(0,9);
    }
print_r($a);
$barcode = 21$a[3-10];
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: what is it youre trying to achieve? generate a 10 digit random number?

Comment: @ImmortalDude I want to generate a 10 digit number where the first two digits are fixed the other 8 is random

Comment: ok so try using `time()` combined with [substr()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [random number generator in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642003/random-number-generator-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you need an 8 digit random number

```
$barcode="21".rand(11111111,99999999);
```

Comment: I would use `mt_rand()`. `$barcode="21".mt_rand(11111111,99999999);`

Comment: As of php7 there is no difference as rand was aliased to mt_rand

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($barcode == NULL)
{
    $a=Array();
    $a[]=2;
    $a[]=1;
    for ($i = 3; $i <=10; $i++)
    {
        $a[] = rand(0, 9);
    }
    $barcode = implode("", $a);
    print_r($barcode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this would work

```
function randomString($length = 50) {
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $string = '';    

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}

$barcode = "21".randomString(8);
```